# Nativescript Vue + Firebase auth: Best way to check if user auth'd in each component?

Tags: firebase-authentication, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am starting to make a Nativescript Vue app and I implemented the Firebase plugin to use the authentication system.
In my `App.vue` file, I have a template that looks like this:

*App.vue*

```
<Page>
   <StackLayout v-if="!loggedIn>
       <LoginComponent />
   <StackLayout
   <StackLayout v-else>
       <MainAppComponent />
   <StackLayout
</Page>
```

In the `LoginComponent`, when a user successfully logs in, I emit an event up to the parent to change `loggedIn` to `true`, so that it shows the `MainAppComponent` and start the regular app flow from there.
Is that a valid way to handle it?  Is there a better way to do it?  I would love to see some input.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using v-if, you may navigate to right component (Login or Main) based on conditional statement, return right component to the frame in main.js

Comment: thanks! Should every time I navigate to components nested off of MainComponent be re-checking if they are logged in or can I assume if they made it to the MainComponent flow, they were logged in so they are good until they manually log out?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

**1. Solution**
Prototype a variable on your `main.js` like that:

```
Vue.prototype.$firebase.init()
```

Now you can use firebase at any place in the app like that: `this.$firebase.getCurrentUser()`

**2. Solution**
Similar to the 1. solution. Create the firebase connection as prototype. Listen to the auth changes. And store the state in either a vuex store or an variable. In this example I use your used variable loggedIn.

```
Vue.prototype.loggedIn = false;
Vue.prototype.$firebase
    .init({
        onAuthStateChanged: function (data) {
            Vue.prototype.loggedIn = data.loggedIn
        }
    })
    .then(
        function (instance) {
            console.log("firebase.init done");
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
        }
);
```

Then you can just access this variable in every component like this: `this.$loggedIn`.
I hope that helps in your project.